# Latex expressions in pandas dataframes not rendering in vscode

Tags: pandas, visual-studio-code, latex, jupyter, mathjax

I am trying to set some labels and the caption of my dataframe using mathjax, but it doesn't render in vscode.

For example, when I do

```
import pandas as pd
test = pd.DataFrame(index=["$\sigma$"])
test
```

I get this as output in my jupyter notebook:

```
$\sigma$
```

Instead of the letter σ. I get the right results if I do the same thing in JupyterLab (in Google Chrome).

Note: Other packages that use mathjax seem to be working fine. Printing latex expressions in matplotlib, sympy and even cells marked with '%%latex' work fine.